# The function f(x) which satisfies fof(x)=4-x

Tags: polynomials

I want to find all $f(x)$s (if they exist) which $fof(x)=4-x$, I know that $f(x)$ can't be linear because if $$f(x)=ax+b$$ then
$$fof(x)=a(ax+b)+b=a^2x+ab+b$$
And $a^2$ can't be -1.

Actually i think $f(x)$ can't be any polynomial but i can't prove it and a combination of trig functions may be an answer.

The answer to my question is a function with that property or a proof that such function doesn't exist. Thanks!

edit:i should be clear that $f$ is $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ and it is injective and continuous.

Comment: why $f(x) = ix + 4/(1+i)$ isn't good? Do you want it real valued?

Comment: might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409811/prove-that-no-function-satisfies-ffx-x3-if-f-mathbb-z-0%e2%86%92-mathbb?noredirect=1

Comment: Is $f$ meant to be from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$?  If so, note that $f$ must be injective (why) and therefore, if it is continuous, it must be monotone.  Derive a contradiction (again, under the additional requirements I spelled out).

Comment: yes $f(x)$ is from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ and i want it to be real not containing complex numbers.

Comment: i also found this function $$f(x)=\sqrt{1-(4-x)^2}+4$$the problem is that $fof(x)$ is $|4-x|$ not $4-x$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If we replace $ x $ by $ f\circ f(x)=f^2(x)  $, we get

$$f^4(x)=4-f^2(x)=x$$

Comment: i didnt get it can you explain the whole solution?